# How to wrap arraylist of string in 'for' function

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, simple-framework

I want to wrap the arraylist of string in 'for' function with usage of simpleXML, retrofit.
How to do it?

```
error:add(com.flower.model.FlowerModel in FlowerModel cannot be applied to(java.lang.String)
```

**In main fragment**:

```
if (response.body().getFlower()!=null){
     for (String flower: response.body().getFlower()){
          FlowerAdapter.add(flower);
     }

}
```

**FlowerAdapter.java**:

```
public void add(FlowerModel model){
        models.add(model);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**ResponseFlower.java**:

```
@Root(name="response",strict = false)
public class ResponseFlower extends ResponseBase{

    @Path("result")
    @ElementArray(entry = "flower")

    private String[] flowerslist;

    public String[] getFlowerlist() {
        return flowerslist;
    }
}
```

**XML Format**:

```
<response>
    <responseId>12345</responseId>
    <status>SUCCESS</status>
    <result>
        <flowers>
            <flower>Lily</flower>
            <flower>Rose</flower>
            <flower>Lavender</flower>
        </flowers>
    </result>
</response>
```

Comment: how FlowerModel look like?

Comment: @Root(name = "flower", strict = false)
public class FlowerModel {

    public FlowerModel(String flower) {
        this.flower = flower;
    }

    @Element
    private String flower;

    public FlowerModel() {

    }

    public String getFlower() {
        return flower;
    }

    public void setFlower(String flower) {
        this.flower = flower;
    }
}

Comment: Check adapter and main fragment, you adapter accepts model class but you are passing String.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending in a `String` to add where the expected method parameter is `FlowerModel`

You will have to send a `FlowerModel` through the `FlowerAdapter` `add` method call.

```
if (response.body().getFlower()!=null){
     for (String flower: response.body().getFlower()){
          // I am assuming its a POJO
          FlowerModel flowerModel = new FlowerModel(); 
          // Assuming you have a method and property to the set the String flower
          flowerModel.setFlower(flower); 
          FlowerAdapter.add(flowerModel);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `response.body().getFlowers()` to get the `List` instead. Then you can loop over it as you are already doing.